# DotNetNuke MVC including cshtml in div

Tags: asp.net, razor, model-view-controller, dotnetnuke

First MVC attempt in DNN.

I have a fairly involved index.cshtml that I'd like to simplify by using jquery's

```
$('#mydiv').load() method.
```

Currently, in the index.cshtml, I'm having to do a bunch of divs like this (very simple) example:

```
<div id="dvBands">
    @using (var ac = new ArtistListingController())
    {
        ac.Gets();
        foreach (var a in ac.Recordset)
        {
            <div>@a.ArtistName</div><br/>
        }
    }
</div>
```

I tried putting the above code in its own _ArtistListing.cshtml and using

```
$('#dvBands').load("tabId/@Dnn.ModuleContext.TabId/moduleId/@Dnn.ModuleContext.ModuleId/controller/Item/action/_ArtistListing")
```

with this in my item controller:

```
public ActionResult _ArtistListing()
{
    return View("_ArtistListing");
}
```

However, not only does it now display the data, it displays the entire page in the div, including the DNN menu and whatnot.

So, how do I separate out my different database calls and include them in the specified div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my index.cshtml ---

```
 @{ Html.RenderPartial("_ArtistListing"); }
```

It looks for a .cshtml file first in the current path and if it can't find it there, in the Shared folders path.

That's it.